# Is there a way to search windows title when pressing super key + S?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

The Search facility of **Super Key**+**S** is fantastic in GNOME.
It would be even more useful if it has ability to filter out active applications by its window title.
What I mean is when you open some file in editor and then open another file in the same editor but separate window, it would be nice to switch to that windows just typing the name of the file.
Instead it looks for some folders with that name, for some files, but not for windows titles.
I have seen some similar questions, so my idea is that there is no such facility although it looks pretty straightforward.
Let it be feature request, then.

Comment: You can make a feature suggest by submitting it as a "bug" at bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu. These types of bugs unfortunately are not usually given a high priority so you may have more luck trying to approach the upstream developers. into the console and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thank you, I am new here, so any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this extension provides facility I am looking for:
https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/5192/ofp-overview-feature-pack/

Comment: it's powerful. but can't filter the Activities Window Thumbnails, only highlight